# Right hand text limit/range indicator line Sublime

Tags: editor, sublimetext2, sublimetext, sublimetext3, sublime-text-plugin

Hi I was wondering if anyone knew of a way to add a vertical range indicator line into Sublime editor either with a package or in the settings? Similar to the one in eclipse that is there by default.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In your settings file you can pass an array:

```
"rulers":
[
    80,
    120, 

],
```

[image]
<sub>(source: [wes.io](http://wes.io/YT50/content))</sub>